# Integration over $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: integration, fourier-transform, coordinate-systems, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

In most applications of multidimensional integration I've seen, e.g. n-dimensional Fourier transforms, and in almost all the introductory and rather heuristic texts such as Riley, Hobson and Bence, we can rewrite the n-dimensional integral as

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}^{} \text{d}^nk = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{d} k_1 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \text{d} k_2 ... $

an iterated integral, if I understand correctly, this follows from Fubini's theorem, which I saw formulated just using the conditions that the integrand $f : [a, b] \times [c, d] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. So do we just take this same argumentation and extend the limits (a, b, c, d) of the domain to infinity?

Further, would it make sense to have, say, a Fourier transform if we can't compute it like an iterated integral? Are there common integrals over $\mathbb{R}^n$ where we cannot use this property? If couldn't do this, could we switch to spherical coordinates? If yes, how would we get the relationship between the volume elements?

Comment: There is much more that can be said, but we certainly universally _hope_ that such manipulations are legitimate in almost all practical situations... A notable exception is trying to prove Fourier inversion by interchange of integrals, but, even then, the idea is not completely "off".

Comment: In general people are using Lebesgue integration and so Fubini Theorem holds as soon as the function $f:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ is integrable or nonnegative.

Comment: @LL3.14 I am not very familiar with Lebesgue integrals. Do you know any books (or other sources) which explain this kind of application to $\mathbb{R}^n$ integration w/o assuming knowledge of Lebesgue integration?

Comment: If you do not want to learn more about Lebesgue integrals, then the only thing you have to know is that Lebesgue integral = Riemann integral when the function is Riemann integrable (so in particular, explicit integrals are still computed the same way) and then as I just told, Fubini Theoem is more general (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem).